# JQuery - list of string

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JQuery, why do I get `information Undefined` with the following code?

> JS - right part is Undefined

```
var s = $("[name='CountAnswer']").val();
```

HTML

```
<input style="width:150px" type="text" id="CountAnswer_1_" name="CountAnswer[1]">
<input style="width:150px" type="text" id="CountAnswer_2_" name="CountAnswer[2]">
<input style="width:150px" type="text" id="CountAnswer_3_" name="CountAnswer[3]">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using equality comparion but you have to use wild card probably j[query attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `^` but the above statement will give value of first matched element. You can use each to iterate through all elements.

```
var s = $("[name^='CountAnswer']").val();
```

Iterating using [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ajean/)**

```
$("[name^='CountAnswer']").each(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
   //or
   alert(this.value);
});
```

**Edit** Based on OP comments. For getting the values of all matches.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ajean/1/)**

```
strValues = $("[name^='CountAnswer']").map(function(){  
   return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

Comment: Ok, but I would like to save this as List of string how to do it?

Comment: Just a tip, next time use `console.log` instead of `alert`. It is annoying when the tab focus changes. :|

Comment: Thanks @DreamEater, but some people do not know about console.log and can not check the output...

Comment: All the more reason to have people be aware about it. Most of the problems regarding [tag:javascript] can be solved that way. :P

Answer (score 5):

Because you don't have an element whose name is == `CountAnswer`. You need to specify a specific name, for example:

```
$("[name='CountAnswer[1]']").val();
```

Alternatively, you could use the "Begins With" wildcard (`^`) to match all elements whose name begins with `CountAnswer`:

```
$("[name^='CountAnswer']").val();
```

This will of course, only return the value of the first element in the matched set, since that is the behaviour of `val()`.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer but Adil gave better

Answer (score 3):

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zHWmG/1)

You should set up an array for your string values, and then on some event use the jquery partial match selector, ["starts with"(^)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), to iterate on the list of inputs denoted by your name.

demo html:

```
<input value="a" style="width:150px" type="text" id="CountAnswer_1_" name="CountAnswer[1]">
<input value="b" style="width:150px" type="text" id="CountAnswer_2_" name="CountAnswer[2]">
<input value="c" style="width:150px" type="text" id="CountAnswer_3_" name="CountAnswer[3]">
<br><input type="button" id="b" value="show string list" /><div id="console"></div>
```

demo js:

```
var stringList = [];
$('#b').click(function(){
 stringList = [];
 $("[name^='CountAnswer']").each(function(){
  stringList.push(this.value);
 });
 var c = $("#console");
 for( var i = 0; i < stringList.length; i++ ){
    var d = $("<div>");
    d.html(stringList[i]);
    c.append(d);
 }
 console.log(stringList);
});
```